# How to prove that $\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 2}$ is irrational

Tags: logarithms, rationality-testing

I have to show that $\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 2}$ is irrational

I have tried the following:

Assume it's rational so

$\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 2} = \frac{p}{q}$

which becomes

$\log _2\left(5\right)=\frac{p}{q}$

Therefore

$5=2^{\frac{p}{q}}$

This is where I'm stuck, I don't know how to advance my proof any further

Comment: Good start!   Use your last equation to deduce $5^q=2^p$.  Why is that not possible?

Comment: ... at least not for $p,q$ positive integers

Comment: With the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), you can even prove it's transcendental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\log 5}{\log 2}=\frac pq\iff 5^q=2^p$$ for naturals $p,q$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and primality of $2$ and $5$, this is not possible.